# Exporting html table to pdf limit data

Tags: java, php, html, css

The output always one single page some data please help me and thanks and the row is 60+ but only 17 data only is the output.

Any function will do in the javascript i search online but i cannot find.

The sample code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#exportButton").click(function () {
        // parse the HTML table element having an id=exportTable
        var dataSource = shield.DataSource.create({
            data: "#exportTable",
            schema: {
                type: "table",
                fields: {
                    Num: { type: Number },
                    Prodcut: { type: String },
                    unitPrice: { type: Number },
                    type: { type: String },
                    lastModified: { type: String },
                    Status: { type: String }
                }
            }
        });

        // when parsing is done, export the data to PDF
         dataSource.read().then(function (data) {
            var pdf = new shield.exp.PDFDocument({
                author: "PrepBootstrap",
                created: new Date()
            });

            pdf.addPage("a4", "landscape");
            pdf.table(
                50,
                50,
                data,
                [
                    { field: "Num", title: "Num", width: 30 },
                    { field: "Prodcut", title: "Prodcut", width: 200 },
                    { field: "unitPrice", title: "unitPrice", width: 90 },
                    { field: "type", title: "type", width: 200 },
                    { field: "lastModified", title: "lastModified", width: 90 },
                    { field: "Status", title: "Status", width: 50 }
                ],
                {
                    margins: {
                        top: 50,
                        left: 50
                    }
                }
            );

            pdf.saveAs({
                fileName: "Report"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you to your suggestion.

[Here the sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwJvL.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the margin add this:

```
margins: {
             top: 50,
             left: 50,
             bottom: 50
         }
```